# What's the default floating point type?

Tags: floating-point, rust

If the floating point type is specified on variable `a`, the `abs` function can be used. The following example is running:

```
fn main() {
    let a = -1.0f64;
    println!("{:?}", a.abs());
}
```

It prints `1` as expected. But if the `f64` is omitted an error is thrown during compilation as in following example:

```
fn main() {
    let a = -1.0;
    println!("{:?}", a.abs());
}
```

This version gives following failure:

```
   Compiling playground v0.1.0 (file:///C:/git/Rust/playground)
src\main.rs:3:24: 3:29 error: no method named `abs` found for type `_` in the current scope
src\main.rs:3     println!("{:?}", a.abs());
                                     ^~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:25: 2:56 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 2:62 note: in expansion of print!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:58 note: in expansion of println!
src\main.rs:3:5: 3:31 note: expansion site
src\main.rs:3:24: 3:29 help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope; the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a `use` for it:
src\main.rs:3:24: 3:29 help: candidate #1: use `core::num::Float`
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `playground`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

This message says the type of `a` is `_`. I guess the `abs` function cannot be used, because it is not clear, what the specific type of `a` is. Does it mean that the type is not defined at compile time? What is the type used, if no specific float type is declared in Rust?

Answer (score 7):

[RFC 212](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0212-restore-int-fallback.md) says:

> Integer literals whose type is unconstrained will default to `i32` [...] Floating point literals will default to `f64`.

However, in most cases something is going to restrict the inferred type to a concrete type, such as by passing it to a method or putting it in a struct.

> Does it mean that the type is not defined at compile time?

The type will *always* be defined before code is actually written out. However, the concrete type of an integer or floating-point literal hovers in a quantum superposition of types until something forces it one way or the other. If nothing forces it, then it would fall back to the default.

That's what ultimately allows code like this to work:

```
use std::{f32, f64};

fn main() {
    let a = -1.0;
    let b = -1.0;

    println!("{:?}", f32::abs(a));
    println!("{:?}", f64::abs(b));
}
```

It might be expected that if the variable is either a `f32` or an `f64`, then go ahead and pick one. I don't know the compiler internals to be able to answer concretely, but it appears that the default type fallback comes into play too late to save your code. When method lookup is occurring, it wants to know the type of the variable to find valid matches, but it's not available yet.

Comment: Why does not the OP's code compile then? ([here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=10e4887dbc2efe616cd1&version=stable))

Comment: If floating point literals will default to `f64`, in above code the `abs` function for `f64` should be used. But the type is not specified as the `_` in the error message suggests.

Comment: @MatthieuM. good question. I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that the order of operations doesn't allow it. I've edited to put my current guess.

Comment: @Shepmaster: well, without specifications it's hard to tell then, but it the compiler is not performing the fallback early enough, it sounds like a bug to me...