# Do literal integral values have a specific type in Rust?

Tags: rust, literals

In https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/primitive-types.html#numeric-types, it said that in

> let x = 42; // x has type i32

That means `x` has the type `i32` as default.

But in http://rustbyexample.com/cast/literals.html, it says that

> Unsuffixed literal, their types depend on how they are used

I know I can't use `i32` to index the vector, but the following code works:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    let j = 1;  // j has default type i32? or it has type when it is first used?
                // And what is the type of 1?

    println!("{}", v[1]); // is 1 a usize?
    println!("{}", v[j]);
}
```

So, what is the type of a literal integral value?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/32697884/155423

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the default integer type in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55903243/what-is-the-default-integer-type-in-rust)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [language reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#integer-literals):

> The type of an *unsuffixed* integer literal is determined by type
>   inference:
>
> - If an integer type can be *uniquely* determined from the surrounding program context, the unsuffixed integer literal has that type.
> - If the program context under-constrains the type, it defaults to the signed 32-bit integer `i32`.
> - If the program context over-constrains the type, it is considered a static type error.

On the line

> ```
> println!("{}", v[1]); // is 1 a usize?
> ```

the surrounding program context requires 1 to be an `usize` (because that's what the `[]` operator needs), so yes, here `1` will have the type `usize`.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning, that the type is not inferred the "first time it is used". If it is used in differing contexts, you will get a compiler error. It will simply not be able to determine the type.

Comment: The quote is not found in the link in 2023. Maybe related: [*Type inference of integer literals is inconsistenct with the reference #104*](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/104)