# Why does a integral literal infer the same type as it is added to instead of i32, the default integral type?

Tags: rust

Why does the variable `no_type` infer to `i8` and not to `i32` (the default type)?

```
fn main() {
    let no_type = 25;

    let int8: i8 = 10;

    let sum = no_type + int8;
    println!("{} + {} = {}", no_type, int8, sum);
}
```

---

What is the type of `x` and `y`?

```
fn main() {
    let x = 12;
    let y = 13;

    println!("{}", x + y);

    let z: i8 = 10;
    println!("{}", z + x);
}
```

Comment: You have specified one of the operands to `i8`, so that type is propagated to the other variables. Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38854408/1233251) answer your question?

Comment: The default is only used when the type can't be inferred.

Comment: Have you seen [How do I print the type of a variable in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423)

Answer (score 4):

There is only one relevant implementation of [`Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) involving an `i8` and a non-reference integer:

```
impl Add<i8> for i8 {
    type Output = i8;
}
```

That means that, for the code to be able to compile, if one side of the addition is known to be an `i8`, the other side must also be. Since  [`{integer}` doesn't have a type yet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41996784/155423), it's free to vary and the compiler assigns it the type `i8`.

This applies once (as in your first code block), twice (as in your second), or as many times as it needs to:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 1 + a;
    let c = 1 + b;
    let d = 1 + c;
    let e = 1 + d;
    let f = 1 + e;
    let g = 1 + f;

    let sum = g + 1i8;

    let _: () = a;   // found type `i8`
    let _: () = sum; // found type `i8`
}
```

> `i32` (the default type)

"Default" isn't the best name for this. It's only used *when type inference couldn't pin down the concrete type*. Thus, you'll often hear this called the "fallback" type.

See also:

- [Do literal integral values have a specific type in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38854408/155423)
- [What is the {integer} in a compiler error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41996784/155423)
- [How do I print the type of a variable in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423)

Comment: thanks a lot. am new to rust and stackoverflow and amazed how helpful ppl hav been

Comment: @r_duck You should consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/225842) if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: @Antonio [The OP doesn't seem to accept any answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9620327/r-duck) for whatever reason.