# Why I can still access a vector's element after taking ownership of it without using reference?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let number_list = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    let n = number_list[0];
    let r = &number_list[0];

    println!("{} : {} : {} : {}", n, r, number_list[0], &number_list[0]);
}
```

The output is:

```
1 : 1 : 1 : 1
```

Another question is what is the difference between vector indexing with a reference and a non-reference except taking the reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a vector of integers ([`i32` to be specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854408/do-literal-integral-values-have-a-specific-type-in-rust?noredirect=1&lq=1)), and `i32` implements the [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait.

[The index syntax returns a dereferenced value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27879161/155423). Since the indexed type implements `Copy`, the compiler copies it implicitly.

You [cannot take ownership of an item from a vector using the indexing syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27904864/155423) at all.

> what is the difference between vector indexing with a reference and a non-reference except taking the reference

Without the `&`, the value is copied (but only because it implements `Copy`). With the `&`, you have a reference to the value inside the vector.